# local audio is not getting stream on remote side

Tags: reactjs, audio, webrtc

I am trying to make an web app with audio, video call using WebRTC.
Problem is that local audio/video working properly in my web app, but remote audio/video is not getting stream on remote side. in console there is no error. you can join room but you can't hear others audio or see video.

here's code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const initRoom = async () => {
            socket.current = socketInit();

            //Get User Audio
            await captureLocalMedia();

            socket.current.emit(ACTIONS.JOIN, {roomId, user});
            socket.current.on(ACTIONS.ADD_PEER, handleNewPeerConnection);

            async function captureLocalMedia() {
                localMediaStream.current =
                    await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                        video: true,
                        audio: true,
                    });
            }

            async function handleNewPeerConnection({peerId, createOffer, user: newUser}) {
                if(peerId in connections.current) {
                    return console.warn(`You are already joined with ${user.username}`)
                }

                var configuration = {
                    offerToReceiveAudio: true
                }

                connections.current[peerId] = new RTCPeerConnection({
                    iceServers: [
                        {
                            urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
                        },
                        {
                            urls: "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302"
                        },
                        {
                            urls: "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302"
                        },
                        {
                            urls: "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302"
                        },
                        {
                            urls: "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302"
                        }
                    ],
                    configuration: configuration
                })


                connections.current[peerId].ontrack = (event) => {
                    addNewClients(newUser, () => {
                        if(audioElements.current[newUser.id]) {
                            audioElements.current[newUser.id].srcObject = event.streams[0];
                        } else {
                            let settled = false;
                            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                                if(audioElements.current[newUser.id]) {
                                    const [remoteStream] = event.streams;
                                    audioElements.current[newUser.id].srcObject=remoteStream
                                    settled = true;
                                }
                                if (settled) {
                                    clearInterval(interval)
                                }
                            }, 600)
                        }
                    })
                }

                localMediaStream.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
                    connections.current[peerId].addTrack(
                        track,
                        localMediaStream.current
                    )
                });

                if(createOffer) {
                    const offer = await connections.current[peerId].createOffer()
                    await connections.current[peerId].setLocalDescription(offer)

                    socket.current.emit(ACTIONS.RELAY_SDP, {
                        peerId,
                        sessionDescription: offer
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        initRoom();

        return () => {
            localMediaStream.current
                .getTracks()
                .forEach((track) => track.stop());

            socket.current.emit(ACTIONS.LEAVE, { roomId });
            for (let peerId in connections.current) {
                connections.current[peerId].close();
                delete connections.current[peerId];
                delete audioElements.current[peerId];
            }
            socket.current.off(ACTIONS.ADD_PEER);
        }
    }, [])
```

this is socketInit function:

```
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';

const socketInit = () => {
    const options = {
        'force new connection': true,
        reconnectionAttempts: 'Infinity',
        timeout: 10000,
        transports: ['websocket'],
    };
    return io('http://localhost:5500', options)
};

export default socketInit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the offer's SDP contains information about media tracks. For example:

```
sdp v=0
o=- 4748410946812024893 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
............
a=sendrecv
**a=msid:Eei3sKzfsiJybxa4TYhANjGsFMuWe2lAxadS f798f673-566e-4a8e-9760-8d657d031acf**
............
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:3563088629 cname:0j/yv49mmBxgcAbW
a=ssrc:3563088629 msid:Eei3sKzfsiJybxa4TYhANjGsFMuWe2lAxadS f798f673-566e-4a8e-9760-8d657d031acf
a=ssrc:3563088629 mslabel:Eei3sKzfsiJybxa4TYhANjGsFMuWe2lAxadS
a=ssrc:3563088629 label:f798f673-566e-4a8e-9760-8d657d031acf
............
a=max-message-size:262144
```

If remote peer got information about media tracks and it doesn't work, then the problem is probably with the playing of HTMLMediaElement. Try to add the line:

```
audioElements.current[newUser.id].autoplay = true
```